# DocuSign Postman - The access token provided is expired, revoked or malformed

Tags: api, postman, docusignapi

I am following the steps on page https://docusign.github.io/postman-esign-api-collection/

I am trying to complete the section that reads

”Replace {iKey} with your integration key and {callback} with your callback URL (set up when you generated the integration key) to obtain consent. This URL opens a DocuSign authentication screen; once you enter your DocuSign username and password, your browser will redirect to your callback URL with a long string returned for the code parameter embedded in the URL. Paste the value of the code parameter into the corresponding value location under Body in the 01 Authorization Code Grant Access Token request and execute it to generate an access token and a refresh token.”

[Screenshot of Postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rkGnS.png)
I have completed these steps but I keep getting an error on postman that reads "The access token provided is expired, revoked or malformed."

To ensure the token wasn’t expired I have re-ran the url to get a fresh code but still no luck.

Im not sure what I am doing wrong ?

[with new uri](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kpc19.png)

Answer (score 1):

Try using this uri: https://account-d.docusign.com/oauth/token assuming its a demo account.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. Im still getting a similar error. I have posted a screenshot in the original question.

Comment: Have you made sure to refresh the code you are entering? It expires within 2 minutes so entering it after that time limit will cause your error.